# ruby: How to step into arbitrary function while debugging

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry, byebug

Let's say I'm stopped on point while debugging:

```
def get_data
    byebug
 => @cache ||= calculate_data
end
```

And `@cache` has value, so on `step` function `calculate_data` won't be executed. But I need to check what's going on inside of `calculate_data` at this exact runtime point.

I can just execute `calculate_data` and see its result in console output, but can I execute function **from debug console** and at same time `step into` it?
(Using byebug or some other debugging tool).

Goal - is to inspect `calculate_data` logic at arbitrary time, particularly when `get_data` called with `@cache` filled.

Comment: Then in that case you have to find `calculate_data ` and put `byebug` in that method. https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/GUIDE.md

Comment: That's incorrect suggestion, because then I will stop on initial calculation (before @cache filled). But described goal - is to inspect `calculate_data` at specific runtime point, particularly when @cache is set.

Comment: Would love to know how to do that too!

Comment: I'm interested in this question too, because Capybara's DSL works in such dynamic way that even settings breakpoint to `/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:237` does not make it stop when I call `attach_file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [pry-moves](https://github.com/garmoshka-mo/pry-moves) you can execute separate debug of arbitrary function from current context:

```
def get_data
    binding.pry
 => @cache ||= calculate_data
end
```

Type `debug calculate_data` to run calculate_data and stop at first line inside of it.

Comment: answering a question from 2016 I like the commitment